# My quickselect algorithm is not returning the correct value

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, quicksort, quickselect

So I'm trying to implement a quickselect algorithm in C++ in order to find the median value in a vector, however it is not properly partially-sorting the list and is also not returning the correct median value.

I can't seem to find where the error is. I'm new to this algorithm and it's my first time trying to implement it. I've included my code below so if anyone more knowledgable than me has any idea on what is going wrong, I would very much appreciate your input.

```
//Returns the index of the object with the kth largest value
int QuickSelect(vector<Object *> & list, int left, int right, int k){

    /*-Base case-*/
    if(left == right) /*List only contains a single element*/
        return left; /*Return that index*/

    int pivotIndex = left + (rand() % (int)(right - left + 1));
    int pivotNewIndex = Partition(list, level, left, right, pivotIndex);
    int pivotDist = pivotNewIndex - left + 1;

    if(pivotDist == k)
        return pivotNewIndex;
    else if (k < pivotDist)
        return QuickSelect(list, level, left, pivotNewIndex-1, k);
    else
        return QuickSelect(list, level, pivotNewIndex+1, right, k-pivotDist);
}


int Partition(vector<Object *> & list, int left, int right, int pivotIndex){

    int pivotValue = list.at(pivotIndex)->value;
    std::swap(list[pivotIndex], list[right]);
    int storeIndex = left;
    for(int i = left; i < right; i++){
        if(list.at(i)->value < pivotValue){
            std::swap(list[storeIndex], list[i]);
            storeIndex++;
        }
    }
    std::swap(list[right], list[storeIndex]);
    return storeIndex;
}
```

Comment: You cannot use the standard one? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element

Comment: Theoretically yes, but I'm trying to gain an understanding of the algorithm by implementing it myself...but I'm currently stuck and need help.

Comment: `QuickSelect` calls `Partition` with an undeclared variable, `level`. If it does not compile, it is hard to debug.

Comment: oh that is my fault, that's not supposed to be in there. it does compile and run...

Answer (score 0):

```
int pivotDist = pivotNewIndex - left + 1;
```

should be

```
int pivotDist = pivotNewIndex - left;
```

Also

```
return QuickSelect(list, pivotNewIndex+1, right, k-pivotDist);
```

should be

```
return QuickSelect(list, pivotNewIndex+1, right, k-pivotDist-1);
```

My test code was:

```
int main() {
  int d[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};

  do {
    std::vector<Object*> v;
    v.push_back(new Object(d[0]));
    v.push_back(new Object(d[1]));
    v.push_back(new Object(d[2]));
    v.push_back(new Object(d[3]));
    v.push_back(new Object(d[4]));

    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
      std::cout << v[i]->value << " "; }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    int n = QuickSelect(v, 0, 4, 2);

    if (v[n]->value != 2) {
      std::cout << "error: ";
      for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << v[i]->value << " "; }
      std::cout << std::endl;
    }
  }
  while (std::next_permutation(&d[0], &d[sizeof(d)/sizeof(int)]));
}
```

Comment: that makes it partially sort the values slightly better but it still does not work.

Comment: @user1782677, fixed. Also, before anyone comments, I know my test code leaks.